# Метод Монте-Карло. Почему пьяница никогда не возвращается в исходную точку?

Tags: c#, случайные-числа, моделирование

Практическая работа по Моделированию.

Город поделён на кварталы. Посреди города расположен бар. Из бара выходит пьяница и проходит 11 кварталов в случайном направлении, выбирая его (направление) каждый раз перед тем как пройти новый квартал. Рассчитать вероятности того, что пьяница не уйдёт от бара дальше, чем на 2 квартала и что пьяница вернётся к бару. Вероятность рассчитывается методом Монте-Карло - ситуация моделируется большое количество раз и количество событий, соответствующих условию делится на общее количество экспериментов.

Сколько не тестировал - вероятность нулевая... Как будто специально он не хочет хоть раз остановиться на изначальной точке.

[Вот проект.](http://yadi.sk/d/2KXyHybmSZy5X)

Вот код метода:

```
void Experiment(Graphics G, int intExperimentCount)
        {

            int intChance2Count = 0;
            int intChance0Count = 0;
            int CX, CY, X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
            int EX, EY, EQX, EQY, EQ;
            CX = 325;
            CY = 325;
            double dblProgress = 0.0;
            double dblProgressStep = 100.0 / intExperimentCount;
            prgrsbrProgress.Value = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= intExperimentCount; i++)
            {
                Random rndmDirection = new Random();
                Pen penWay = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
                SolidBrush sldbrshStop = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                int intDirection;

                X2 = CX;
                Y2 = CY;
                for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    X1 = X2;
                    Y1 = Y2;
                    intDirection = rndmDirection.Next(1, 5);
                    switch (intDirection)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            X2 = X2 - 25;
                            G.DrawLine(penWay, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Y2 = Y2 + 25;
                            G.DrawLine(penWay, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            X2 = X2 + 25;
                            G.DrawLine(penWay, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Y2 = Y2 - 25;
                            G.DrawLine(penWay, X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                G.FillEllipse(sldbrshStop, X2 - 3, Y2 - 3, 6, 6);
                EX = Math.Abs(X2 - CX);
                EY = Math.Abs(Y2 - CY);
                EQX = EX / 25;
                EQY = EY / 25;
                EQ = EQX + EQY;
                if (EQ <= 2)
                    intChance2Count++;
                if (EQ == 0)
                    intChance0Count++;
                if (prgrsbrProgress.Value < 100)
                {
                    dblProgress = dblProgress + dblProgressStep;
                    prgrsbrProgress.Value = (int)dblProgress;
                }
                else
                    prgrsbrProgress.Value = 100;
                if (chkbxSlow.Checked == true)
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            double dblChance2 = Convert.ToDouble(intChance2Count) / Convert.ToDouble(intExperimentCount);
            double dblChance0 = Convert.ToDouble(intChance0Count) / Convert.ToDouble(intExperimentCount);
            ListViewItem lstvwtmNewExperiment = new ListViewItem(intExperimentCount.ToString());
            lstvwtmNewExperiment.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(dblChance2, 8).ToString());
            lstvwtmNewExperiment.SubItems.Add(Math.Round(dblChance0, 8).ToString());
            lstvwResults.Items.Add(lstvwtmNewExperiment);
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы правы - это из-за нечётного количества "шагов".

Comment: Вообще-то, это вопрос на математику (http://math.hashcode.ru).

Comment: Теперь я это понял. Но до этого думал, что проблема в коде. Поэтому и разместил вопрос здесь. Прошу KoVadim преобразовать свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

то что он вернется к бару - нулевая вероятность, так как он проходит нечетное количество кварталов.

А вот то, что будет в двух кварталах - тут вероятность какая то есть. Думаю, Вы просто мало экспериментов делаете.

Написал маленькую программу на плюсах, что бы посчитать все возможные варианты.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int get_c(int n, int x, int y) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return (x*x + y*y <= 4)?1:0; // комментарий ниже
    }
    int r = 0;
    r += get_c(n-1, x-1, y);
    r += get_c(n-1, x+1, y);
    r += get_c(n-1, x, y-1);
    r += get_c(n-1, x, y+1);
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int step = 11;
    int total = pow(4,step);
    int count = get_c(step,0,0);
    std::cout << "count " << count << std::endl;
    std::cout << "total " << total << std::endl;
    std::cout << "      " << count * 100.0 / total << "%" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В коде используется 4, потому что там небольшая оптимизация. Вообще то нужно было бы написать что то  вида

```
return (sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= 2)?1:0;
```

Но смысл каждый раз вычислять корень?

И ответ

```
count 853776
total 4194304
      20.3556%
```